# Global Value Set is not translated in managed package

Tags: managed-package, translation, 2gp

I developed a 2GP managed package.

I enabled the translation workbench in the package and translated custom fields.
These are well working in the organization where the package is installed.

I also implemented the translation of Global Value SET.
But these are not working in the installed organization.

I Excute `sfdx force:source:push` for different scratch organizations, but translation was working.
Is there anyone who has similar problems?

share the command that I created the package.

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -d force-app --package XXXXXXX --installationkeybypass --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --codecoverage--wait 10
```